# Fluent-bit log forwarder issue

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, rancher, fluent-bit

I have application deployed on kubernetes container along with logger `SideCar` [fluent/fluent-bit:1.0.6](https://fluentbit.io/announcements/v1.0.6/) using  But logger container fails with below error. Since fluent.conf comes inside docker image does any know how to fix below error

Error in logger container:

```
[2021/04/01 20:53:10] [  Error] File /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
[2021/04/01 20:53:10] [  Error] Error in line 33: Invalid indentation level
```

My deployment YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-pt
  labels:
    app: my-pt
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-pt
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-pt
         
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: my-pt
        image: myimage
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: log
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 8080
       
# Logging sidecar.
      - name: logger
        env:
          - name: NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: POD_UID
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.uid
        image: fluent/fluent-bit:1.0.6
        # Above image is not bundled with sh,bash etc, for troubleshooting add -debug to the image name,
        # for eg. fluent/fluent-bit:1.0.4-debug  
        command: ["/fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit"]
        args:
        - --config=/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
        - --parser=/fluentd/etc/parsers.conf
        volumeMounts:
        - name: log
          mountPath: /log
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc
      # Create a volume to share between containers for writing and reading logs.
      volumes:
      - name: log
        emptyDir: {}
      # fluent bit config files.
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: bit-config
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems syntax issue.. share the fluent-bit.conf definition